# Python Code of this definition

Tags: python

```
FUNCTIONS = {
    "I2C": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {0:"SDA", 1:"SCL", 2:"SDA", 3:"SCL"}, "modules": ["i2c-bcm2708", "i2c-dev"]},
    "SPI": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {7:"CE1", 8:"CE0", 9:"MISO", 10:"MOSI", 11:"SCLK"}, "modules": ["spi-bcm2708", "spidev"]},
    "UART": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {14:"TX", 15:"RX"}},
    "ONEWIRE": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {4:"DATA"}, "modules": ["w1-gpio"], "wait": 2}
}
```

Not sure of this, is that a array? dictionary?  {} and []?  key and value pair?

Answer (score 3):

`FUNCTIONS` is a dictionary, and the direct values are dictionaries too.

The `gpio` keys in the nested dictionaries are more dictionaries, and the `modules` keys are associated with list objects.

Python containers can hold other containers; the `{...}` curly braces with `key: value` pairs form a dictionary, the `[...]` square brackets define lists.

You can introspect and play with the structure in a Python interpreter; the `type()` function will tell you the object type:

```
>>> FUNCTIONS = {
...     "I2C": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {0:"SDA", 1:"SCL", 2:"SDA", 3:"SCL"}, "modules": ["i2c-bcm2708", "i2c-dev"]},
...     "SPI": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {7:"CE1", 8:"CE0", 9:"MISO", 10:"MOSI", 11:"SCLK"}, "modules": ["spi-bcm2708", "spidev"]},
...     "UART": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {14:"TX", 15:"RX"}},
...     "ONEWIRE": {"enabled": False, "gpio": {4:"DATA"}, "modules": ["w1-gpio"], "wait": 2}
... }
>>> type(FUNCTIONS)
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(FUNCTIONS['I2C'])
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(FUNCTIONS['I2C']['modules'])
<type 'list'>
```